# Data Scrubbing and Reformatting

Tags: python, data-scrubbing

Python Code

Scrubbing and reformatting data is a real world problem in computer science, it is the process of taking in a human input that may be in the incorrect format and cleaning it up to put it in a standard format. How can I write a program that asks someone to enter a phone number and then returns that phone number in a standard format if possible otherwise giving an error.

Examples:

Please enter a phone number including area code: 607-8675309

(607)867-5309

Please enter a phone number including area code: 16078675309

(607)867-5309

Please enter a phone number including area code: (607) Jenny I got your number, I need to make you mine, Jenny don't change your number, 8675309

(607)867-5309

Comment: Q: Can you post any code for what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to cleanup/validate phone number formatting using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean the input fields and check against your desired output and return the a message accordingly. Python web frameworks like [Django](http://djangoproject.com/), [Web2py](http://www.web2py.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) exists to precisely help with these types of problems.